# Resources loading over https connection

Tags: node.js, http-headers

I have a nodejs app and i works fine in my local machine. But as soon as i deploy it on my development server(over http) it fails to reload resources as its trying to load resources over https connection.

Is there any way to force browser to load resources over http instead of https?

Edit:
http://18.188.5.74:5000/ this is the link where the problem arises, you can see errors in console

Update:
The problem was with default CSP. After setting custom CSP with resp.set() method of express I was able to overcome this issue.

Comment: You would have to show the structure of whatever you're talking about so we can see why both the http and https are happening.  There's no generic control here.  When a resource has an `http` at the start of it's URL, it will use `http` and when it starts with `https`, it will use `https`.  If a resource inside of a web page has no protocol and just starts with `/` or even just the filename, then it will inherit the protocol of the parent web page.  So, your issue has to do with whatever URLs you are using.

Comment: I am using dynamic urls eg. /Static/css/style.css, so in source code it is http link, but when chrome loads those resources it uses https for some reason. http://18.188.5.74:5000/ this is the link you can inspect on

Comment: I suspect it has to do with the `Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests` that your server sends back as a header when the http version of the web page is first requested.  This directs Chrome to change http requests to https requests to that host. Actually, the full header from your server is this `Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self';base-uri 'self';block-all-mixed-content;font-src 'self' https: data:;frame-ancestors 'self';img-src 'self' data:;object-src 'none';script-src 'self';script-src-attr 'none';style-src 'self' https: 'unsafe-inline';upgrade-insecure-requests`.

Comment: You can Google `update-insecure-requests` to learn a lot more about it, but it looks like something your server should change if you want to only use `http`.  My guess is that it's either required by your hosting company or it's a configuration option.

Comment: Any idea how can I remove any of these Content-Security-Policy these seems to be default Policies. I am not sending any response header from server itself